# Add a <td> when choosing an option in select menu JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a form with all kinds of data, but i want one thing to work, i have a country dropdown that is named `land`. i want it so that if i choose Nederland that there is a new column in the row that is named provincie. But if i choose an other country than it is just country and `provincie` shouldn't show up. i will provide you with as much as possible,

via this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/

I will also put the code here because stackoverflow recommended it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nadal.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="submit"]').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          formIsValid = true;

          var errors = [];
          $('.errors').html("");

          $('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
              formIsValid = false;
              message = $(this).attr('id') + ' is verplicht';
              errors.push(message);
              $(this).addClass("red");
            } else{
              $(this).removeClass("red");
            }
          });


          if (formIsValid == true) {
            $('.data').append('<tr class="datarow"><td>'+$('input[name="name"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="email"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="phone_number"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#land option:selected').text()+'</td><td class="delete">X</td></tr>');
            updateTotalRows();

            $('.delete').click(function() {
              $(this).parent().remove();
              updateTotalRows();
            })
          }
        });

        function updateTotalRows() {
          $('.total').html('Ik heb nu : ' + $('.datarow').length + ' rows');
        }
      }); 
    </script>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div class="errors"></div>
      <input type="text" id="Naam" class="required" name="name" placeholder="name" >
      <input type="email" id="Email" name="email" class="required" placeholder="email">
      <input type="number" id="Telefoonnummer" name="phone_number" class="required" placeholder="phone">
      <select name="land" id="land">
        <option value="Nederland">Nederland</option>
        <option value="Duitsland">Duitsland</option>
        <option value="Frankrijk">Frankrijk</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <form id="myFormCorrect">
      <table id="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>telefoonnummer</th>
            <th>Land</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="data">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    <div class="total"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
.red {
  border-color:red;   
}

.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #FFF;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: can you check this https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/1/

Comment: sorry couldnt understand your question... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/2/  is this what you want?

Comment: updated https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/3/ is what i want, but the provincie wont show up in the table when you submit.

Comment: @NadalRahman check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o8jrb4sj/4/)

Comment: This almost did the trick the provincie header shows up but not the provincie you typed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these 2 fiddles. First one is for getting the value from the dropdown. (In your case "Netherlands") http://jsfiddle.net/zwzakdnv/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mydropdown').change(function(){
        $selected_value=$('#mydropdown option:selected').text();
        $('#result').text($selected_value);
    });
});
```

And second one http://jsfiddle.net/Jaganathan/R2Her/ to dynamically add columns are rows to your table.

```
<table border="1" id="mtable">
<thead><tr><td>Item</td><td>Red</td><td>Green</td></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>Some Item</td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td><input type="checkbox"/></td></tr></tbody>
```

Insert Row
Insert Column

and the Js

```
$('#irow').click(function(){
if($('#row').val()){
    $('#mtable tbody').append($("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone());
    $('#mtable tbody tr:last :checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    $('#mtable tbody tr:last td:first').html($('#row').val());
}else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
$('#icol').click(function(){
if($('#col').val()){
    $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>"));
    $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
    $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function()    {$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="checkbox">'))});
}else{alert('Enter Text');}
});
```

For removing columns/rows that shouldn't show up just give a class to the div with style not visible and toggle the div when you want to show/remove it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nadal.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="submit"]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            formIsValid = true;

            var errors = [];
            $('.errors').html("");

            $('input.required').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    formIsValid = false;
                    message = $(this).attr('id') + ' is verplicht';
                    errors.push(message);
                    $(this).addClass("red");
                } else{
                    $(this).removeClass("red");
                }
            });


            if (formIsValid == true) {
                    var provincie ="";
                if ($('.province' ).val().trim() !="") {
                    provincie = $('.province' ).val();
                }

                $('.data').append('<tr class="datarow"><td>'+$('input[name="name"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="email"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="phone_number"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#land option:selected').text()+ ' ' + provincie +'</td><td class="delete">X</td></tr>');
                updateTotalRows();


                $('.delete').click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    updateTotalRows();
                })
            }
        });

        function updateTotalRows() {
            $('.total').html('Ik heb nu : ' + $('.datarow').length + ' rows');
        }

        $('#land').on('change', function(){
            if($("#land").val()=="Nederland"){
                $('.province').show();
                $('#table thead tr th:contains(Province)').show();
            }
            else{
                $('.province').hide();
                $('#table thead tr th:contains(Province)').hide();
            }
        });

    }); 
</script>



<form id="myForm">
    <div class="errors"></div>

    <input type="text" id="Naam" class="required" name="name" placeholder="name" >
    <input type="email" id="Email" name="email" class="required" placeholder="email">
    <input type="number" id="Telefoonnummer" name="phone_number" class="required" placeholder="phone">

    <select name="land" id="land">
        <option value="Nederland">Nederland</option>
        <option value="Duitsland">Duitsland</option>
        <option value="Frankrijk">Frankrijk</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="province" placeholder="enter province">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>



<form id="myFormCorrect">

    <table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Naam</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>telefoonnummer</th>
                <th>Land</th>
                <th>Province</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="data">

        </tbody>

    </table>

</form>

<div class="total"></div>

</body>
</html>
```